# TACACS+ accounting using linux client

Tags: linux, logs, tacacs+

Is it possible to log all commands executed in the Linux machine to a TACACS server?

Comment: Don't use tacacs+, then at least use radius instead. If you are looking for some central registry, then use directory services such as 389DS, preferably with kerberos.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.